# My c++ loop doesn't stop when i tell it to do it through the console

Tags: c++

I have made a loop which should encrypt the phrases I tell it to, but didn't finish because of the problem. It should detect when I say "stop" in the console and shut down the loop. It doesn't work.
What i want it to do is to detect if i said stop and break the loop. I shouldn t get any random missfires from getting the letters s t o p from other words. As you can see, every time there is a letter out of order, it resets the vectors which locks all of the ifs until 'c' gets the correct letters in the correct order.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char c,v[5];
  int i=0;
    while(i!=1)
    {
        cin.get(c);
        if(c=='s' or v[1]=='s')
        {
            v[1]='s';
            if(c=='t' or v[2]=='t')
            {
                v[2]='t';
                if(c=='o' or v[3]=='o')
                {
                    v[3]='o';
                    if(c=='p' or v[4]=='p')
                    {
                        v[4]='p';
                        v[1]=v[2]=v[3]=v[4]=0;
                        i=1;
                    }
                    else
                        v[1]=v[2]=v[3]=0;
                }
                else
                    v[1]=v[2]=0;
            }
            else
              v[1]=0;
        }
        cout<<c;
        if (i==1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `c` is a single `char` that you read from user input. It cannot be `s`, `t`, `o` and `p` at the same time, but thats the only case where you modify `i`

Comment: it has to be only one time, each of the above letters. Once c becomes s, the first if is locked , then if it becomes t the second if locks open because of the vector becoming s until c becomes the wrong letter and resets the vectors

Comment: It can't "become" anything; you read one character then never change it

Comment: it is in a loop, it reads character by character, updating the  vectors

Comment: for example, if c is 's' then the first if gets unlocked and makes the vector v[1] ='s' and the if remains open until c has the wrong value

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and better explain what exactly you expect the behavior of your code to be. I know your logic can't possibly work but I am not 100% sure what you want to happen.

Comment: @drescherjm The array ("vector") holds the characters of "stop" that have already been typed. Or rather, it's meant to.

Comment: You type `s` and now c contains 's'. The computer checks whether c contains 's'. It does so it runs the if statement. The computer sets `v[1]='s';`. The computer then checks whether c contains 't' or v[2] contains 't'. It does not so the computer runs the 'else' statement which sets `v[1]=0;` again. End result: nothing happens.

Comment: Also `v` is never initialized, so it contains random values.

Comment: ah yes, thats true, i am starting to wonder why didn  i see this until now

Comment: Do you just want to write code that checks if the characters 's', 't', 'o', and 'p' were entered in order followed by a single hit of the return key? Or do you have to have the return key pressed in between characters? Because there are easier ways to achieve what you're aiming for.

Comment: i added break in every if, it works now by stopping the chain when the correct value has been detected

Comment: it works now, thanks to everyone that helped me.

Answer (score 2):

That should the work and is not indented hell code. It assumes that you are entering one character at a time.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char keyword[] = "stop";
    char* matching_char = keyword;
    char char_from_user;
    while(*matching_char != '\0')
    {
        std::cin.get(char_from_user);
        // Reset if different character
        if(*matching_char != char_from_user)
            matching_char = keyword;

        // Increment position of match
        if(*matching_char == char_from_user)
            ++matching_char;
        // Ignore rest in buffer
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, you just need to assign the v array values after each if/else condition otherwise it will just get immediately reassigned to 0. For example, you first assign v[1] = 's', and then right after you assign it to v[1] = 0, because the if returns false in first iteration. The following code should solve the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char c,v[5];
  int i=0;
    while(i!=1)
    {
        cin.get(c);
        if(c=='s' || v[1]=='s')
        {
            if(c=='t' || v[2]=='t')
            {
                if(c=='o' || v[3]=='o')
                {
                    if(c=='p' || v[4]=='p')
                    {
                        v[4]='p';
                        v[1]=v[2]=v[3]=v[4]=0;
                        i=1;
                    }
                    else
                        v[1]=v[2]=v[3]=0;
                    v[3]='o';
                }
                else
                    v[1]=v[2]=0;
                v[2]='t';
            }
            else
              v[1]=0;
            v[1]='s';
        }
        if (i==1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: tanks it helped alot